# Windows 7: Playing DVD shows gray Noise

Tags: windows-7, video, dvd

I've got a Windows 7 computer. When I want to watch a DVD movie, it starts playing, but nearly immediately the whole screen shows gray noise. When pressing ESC, the noise disappears for a moment and I can verify that my DVD is really being played. This happens with VLC as well as with Windows Media Player. I have to press CTR-ALT-DEL, followed by ESC to stop playing the DVD.

I've looked through all the autostart programs, but I could not find anything that could cause this strange behavior. My video card is a GeForce GTX 750 Ti using the GeForce drivers.

I've tested with several different DVDs that all work without problem on other computers. And the DVD drive works without any problem with computer games.

Comment: Have you tried playing a different DVD on your computer? Or have you tried playing that same DVD on another device?

Comment: @PseudoSu Yes, I did both. As I've already mentioned in my question. :-)